# Angular js typeahead is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I have to enable the autocomplete functionality in the search box to display the list of states as and when I start typing the state's name. I tried using typeahead attribute, it is not working. Please find the code snippet below.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="dlcProjectApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content=""/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-require="angular.js@*" src="angularjs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-require="angular-animate@*" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="projectApp.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>

body {
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
}

img { width: 30px; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
            <div ng-app="dlcProjectApp">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="dlcProjectController">
        <h2><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo"> Angular.js Typeahead</h2>

          <label for="states4">Search for US States</label>
            <input name="states1" id="states2" type="text" placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states" class="form-control">

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

```
var dlcProject = angular.module('dlcProjectApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
dlcProject.factory("States", function(){
      var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

      return states;

    });
dlcProject.controller('dlcProjectController',function($scope,$http,$compile,$timeout,States){
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = States;
     });
```

Comment: here is an [example](http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv?editors=1010)

Comment: I tried the same example. It is not working for me.

Comment: I tried the same example. It is working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LetOsHurqNG8VW2Ayl8D?p=preview)

May be you did not add the external library properly. Type-ahead is dependent on `ui-bootstrap-tpls`. Add a valid `cdn` of `ui-bootstrap-tpls`, it should work.

```
<script   src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried including this file. But, it is not working.

Comment: Check my plnkr..... For testing purpose, I suggest you to replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.min.js"></script>` with `<script   src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>`. Then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

add "uib-" prefix to typeahead in your html file.